# Encoding a set of three integers to one unique number

Tags: java

So, my problem set is very simple. I am working with a set of three integers randomly selected from **[0-65535]** and my Job is to encode this integers into one unique number. Here is what I have tried so far

I have written a java function called `pack` to try and encode this numbers as follows

```
 private long pack(long a, long b, long c) {
        int N = 65535, M = 65536;
        return (a + (b * N) + c * N * M);
    }
```

And I have also written another java function to unpack or decode the packed number back to the original integers as follows

```
private long[] unpack(long packed) {
    int N = 65535, M = 65536;
    long a = (packed % N);
    long b = (packed / N) % M;
    long c = (packed % (N * M));
    return new long[]{a, b, c};
}
```

Now when I ran the code above in my main function using sample data `{67, 8192, 7168}`  I am getting the following as result in my console output

```
Packing 67, 8192, 7168
Result=30786392678467

UnPacking 30786392678467
Result=[67, 8192, 57411]
```

From the above, clearly my first and second values are always correct but the last value always appear to be wrong. What am I possibly missing out.Your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks alot.

Comment: Hi Mekings. Since 65,535 = 2^16 – 1, you may also consider using a `char` array. In Java, a `char` is a 16-bit datatype (2 bytes). See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_characters.htm for pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your packing and unpacking code is incorrect according to the range [0, 65535] you've given.

There are 65,536 possible numbers, and you don't want the encoding of one integer to change the encoding of another integer.  You should use one constant set to `65536` (which is 2<sup>16</sup>).

```
public static final long PACK = 65536;
```

Then your `pack` method changes slightly to:

```
private long pack(long a, long b, long c) {
    return (a + (b * PACK) + c * PACK * PACK);
}
```

This "packs" `a` into the least significant 16 bits of the long (bits 49-64), `b` into bits 33-48, and `c` into bits 17-32.  (Nothing is packed into bits 0-16, so those bits remain cleared.)

Also, your `unpack` method changes to:

```
private static long[] unpack(long packed) {
    long a = (packed % PACK);
    long b = (packed / PACK) % PACK;
    long c = (packed / (PACK * PACK));  // Use / not %.
    return new long[]{a, b, c};
}
```

Notice that `c`'s operation divides by `PACK` squared, not using the `%` operator, but using `/`.  Otherwise both `M` and `N` have each been replaced by `PACK`.

Output with these changes:

```
Packing 67, 8192, 168
Result=722091376707

UnPacking 722091376707
Result=[67, 8192, 168]
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to give you an alternative solution now, and then I can try to debug your current solution when I'm on a PC instead of a phone ([rgettman beat me!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54814507/7294647)).

Because each of the three numbers can be a maximum of 65535, that means that each number will fit into 16 bits. For that reason, you can simply build a unique `long` with the following:

```
long encoded = (a << 32L) | (b << 16) | c;
```

And decoding it would look like the following:

```
long a = (encoded >> 32) & 0xFFFFL;
long b = (encoded >> 16) & 0xFFFFL;
long c = encoded & 0xFFFFL;
```

Comment: Awesome..This also works...Thanks alot. I truly appreciate your effort and time..

Answer (score 1):

actually, your solution is almost correct: just make sure that M == N == 65536 and fix the problem in unpacking variable **c**.

```
private long pack(long a, long b, long c) {
    long N = 65536;
    return (a + (b * N) + c * N * N);
}

private long[] unpack(long packed) {
  long N = 65536;
  long a = (packed % N);
  long b = (packed / N) % N;
  long c = (packed / (N * N));
  return new long[]{a, b, c};
}
```

Also, I changed the type of N to **long** although it would not matter as Java will convert it to **long** during multiplication anyway.